# Using select for change url feed in jquery.rss

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, rss-reader

i have one problem, i want to use select element for change url of my list using the plugin https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss.

This link, is my code with select, but not functional:
http://jsfiddle.net/diegomachado/ktz5g892/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://unsplash.com/rss", {
        limit: 10,
        layoutTemplate: '<ul>{entries}</ul>',
        entryTemplate: '<li>{teaserImageUrl}</li>',
        effect: 'slideFastSynced'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
<select class="feed-source">
    <option value="http://unsplash.com/rss">http://unsplash.com/rss</option>
    <option value="http://antbaena.tumblr.com/rss">http://antbaena.tumblr.com/rss</option>
    <option value="http://devon-jade.tumblr.com/rss">http://devon-jade.tumblr.com/rss</option>
</select>
<h1>jquery.rss example</h1>
<div id="rss-feeds"></div>
```

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://unsplash.com/rss", {
        limit: 10,
        layoutTemplate: '<ul>{entries}</ul>',
        entryTemplate: '<li>{teaserImageUrl}</li>',
        effect: 'slideFastSynced'
    })

    $(".feed-source").change(function(){
        $("#rss-feeds").html("");
        $("#rss-feeds").rss($(".feed-source").val(), {
            limit: 10,
            layoutTemplate: '<ul>{entries}</ul>',
            entryTemplate: '<li>{teaserImageUrl}</li>',
            effect: 'slideFastSynced'
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you moved the RSS feed call into a re-usable method e.g. `function loadRss(url) { .. }`